# Telnet connection and issue while sending input to the server

Tags: perl

I have written the server program using the select. Then I have connect the client using telnet. The connection also completed successfully.

If I have the input length as 6 character including newline, in the server side it display the length as 7 character. How it is possible?

Comment: could you post some code? could you post what you're actually getting as the server and client see it?

Comment: Telnet adds a lot of cruft.  Use ncat or netcat or nc or pretty much anything other than telnet.

Comment: If I want to remove those character what I have to do?

Answer (score 1):

**Server side:**

The client is sending `\r\n` instead of `\n`, which would account for the extra character.  You can translate it back to just a newline with a simple regex:

```
# $data holds the input line from the client.
$data =~ s/\r\n/\n/g;  # Search for \r\n, replace it with \n
```

**Client side:**

Assuming you're using [Net::Telnet](http://search.cpan.org/~jrogers/Net-Telnet-3.03/lib/Net/Telnet.pm), you're probably sending 2 characters for the newline, `\r` and `\n`, as specified by the [Telnet RFC](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc854.html).

The documentation I linked to says this,

> In the input stream, each sequence of
>   carriage return and line feed (i.e.
>   "\015\012" or CR LF) is converted to
>   "\n". In the output stream, each
>   occurrence of "\n" is converted to a
>   sequence of CR LF. See binmode() to
>   change the behavior. TCP protocols
>   typically use the ASCII sequence,
>   carriage return and line feed to
>   designate a newline.

And the default is not binary mode (binmode), meaning that all instances of `\n` in your client data will be replaced by `\r\n` before it gets sent to the server.

> The default Binmode is 0, which means
>   do newline translation.

You can stop the module from replacing your newlines by calling `binmode` on your file descriptor, or in the case of Net::Telnet, call `binmode` on your object and pass 1.

```
# Do not translate newlines.
$obj->binmode(1);
```

Or on the server you can search for `\r\n` on the input data and replace it with `\n`.